# Unpacking variable length list returned from function

Tags: python

Ok so I'm defining a function that takes a variable number of inputs and clamps each of them

```
def clamp(*args):
    return [ max(min(arg, 0.8), 0.2) for arg in args]
```

I like the readability of this function:

```
a = 0.12
b = 0.45
c = 0.992

A,B,C = clamp(a,b,c)

print A,B,C

>> 0.2, 0.45, 0.8
```

This takes advantage of python's automatic unpacking of lists to tuples. The trouble I am having is that if I only give one argument, python doesn't unpack it from the list and I get a list instead of a float, which is annoying.

```
print clamp(a)

>> [0.2]
```

My solution so far is to check the length of the list and index it if there is only one element:

```
def clamp(*args):
    result = [ max(0.2, min(0.8,arg)) for arg in args]
    return result if len(result) > 1 else result[0]

a = 0.12
print clamp(a)

>> [0.2]
```

My question is, is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you just print `clamp(a)[0]`, given that you know it will return a single element list?

Comment: This is a bad idea (so I'm not putting it as an answer), but you can actually do `A, = clamp(a)`.

Comment: I'd expect most cases where you'd need to clamp things, you'd either be clamping 1 thing or all elements of a sequence. You could try a 1-arg clamp and write `A, B, C = map(clamp, (a, b, c))` if you need to clamp 3 things at once.

Comment: @user2357112 In this case I actually have three variables since I am working with HSV color palettes (hue, saturation, value) - for readability it doesn't make sense to put those values in a list. However, your use of map is good, I like that approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very conviced but here is an alternative solution

```
>>> clam = lambda a: max(min(a, 0.8), 0.2)

>>> def clamp(a, *args):
...     if args:
...        return [ clam(arg) for arg in (a,)+args]
...     else:
...        return clam(a)
... 
>>> clamp(123, 123)
[0.8, 0.8]
>>> clamp(123)
0.8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can force it to unpack a single element by adding a comma after the name.  Not ideal but here you go:

```
A, = clamp(a)
```

Comment: By the same token, you could do

    `A = clamp(a)[0]`  but I think it would be better to do the work _inside_ the function

Answer (score 0):

```
def clamp(*args):
    rt = [max(min(arg, 0.8), 0.2) for arg in args]
    return rt if len(rt) > 1 else rt[0]
```

or else, remember how you make a tuple of one element. Put a comma after `A` to force unpack for a single variable.

```
A, = clamp(0.12) # with your old function which always returns list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def clamp(*args):
    lst = [max(min(arg, 0.8), 0.2) for arg in args]
    if len(lst)==1:
        return lst[0]
    return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you call it with one element, you can add a `,` after the name. `a, = clamp(1)`. In this case, you don't have to modify your function and the automatic unpacking still happens.

```
>>> a, b, c = [1,2,3]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
>>> a, = [1]
>>> a
1
>>>
```