# I'm looking for a neat way to return multiple matrices in python

Tags: python, matrix, iterable-unpacking

I'm trying to find a neater way of returning an arbitrary number of NxN matrices.
Right now I'm using this function

```
from numpy import matrix, zeros

def empty_matrix( dim, num ):   
"""Returns an empty square matrix of type complex and size a."""
    if num == 1:
        return matrix(zeros(shape =( dim, dim ), dtype=complex))
    else:
        return [ matrix(zeros(shape =( dim, dim ), dtype=complex)) for _ in range( num )]
```

in the following way:

```
A,B,C = empty_matrix( 2, 3 ) # sets A, B, C as 3 2x2 matrices
```

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to avoid the if/else statement. Any ideas?

Comment: You can find some solutions in this [question][1]. Hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869775/unpacking-variable-length-list-returned-from-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `if num == 1`, and use a 1-element-tuple-unpacking:

```
A,B,C = empty_matrices( 2, 3 ) # sets A, B, C as 3 2x2 matrices
A, = empty_matrices( 2, 1 ) # sets A as a 2x2 matrix
```