# Returning all the elements of a list without knowing their number python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there's a way to create a function that returns an unknown number of values?

I was trying to use a list of all the values I'm trying to return and iterating
through them - no success.

Edit:

the real problem is the fact that i do not know how much variables i will have when the function terminates...

Comment: If you tried something, you should include that code in your question.

Comment: my tries are really bad and i did not find anything about this on the site

Comment: Have a look at [Unpacking variable length list returned from function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869775/unpacking-variable-length-list-returned-from-function)

Comment: You seem to be saying you're attempting to build a function that returns a list but you're unable to do so. However, it's hard to see how that would be true. Please post some code to back up your claim so that we can re-evaluate it.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at `*args` and `**kwargs` - [here](http://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/).

```
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    return [a for a in args]


>>>test('one', 'two', None, 6)
['one', 'two', None, 6]
```

Comment: This may not be necessary depending on what the OP's question means. Unfortunately, that is not clear enough to determine.